# Getting locations from breweryDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

i am fetching data from breweryDB and i get all the beer data i need, so that is great! but what i want to do now is to get the location where the beer is made. in the endpoint /beers
        or /beer/beerId i dont see anything about location or which brewery they are made in. there is an endpoint /locations, but i dont know how to connect them to beers.

```
    at the moment i cam fetching beer like this:


    loadBeer = (beerId) => {
        //console.log(`Loading beer ${beerId}`);
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        const key = "000000";
        fetch(`http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/beer/${beerId}?key=${key}`)
          .then((data) => data.json())
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res, "info");
            this.setState({ beer: res.data, loading: false });
          })
          .catch((err) => console.error(err));
      };

and beers like this :

const key = "00000";
    fetch(`http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/search/?key=${key}&q=${searchTerm}`)
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((beers) => {
        this.setState({
          beers: beers.data.filter((beer) => !!beer.labels),
          loading: false,
        });
        console.log(beers, "beers");
        // save to local storage in case search for this again
        localStorage.setItem(
          `search-${searchTerm}`,
          JSON.stringify(this.state.beers)
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };
```

but in neither of them i can't find anything to connect to breweries or location when i look at the json files. does anyone have experience with this api and does anyone know how to help me to get the right data i need?

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following API description pages:

- https://brewerydb.com/developers/docs/endpoint/beer-brewery
- https://brewerydb.com/developers/docs/endpoint/brewery-location

It appears you can get a list of breweries at:

```
/beer/:beerId/breweries
```

For each brewery, you can get a list of locations at:

```
/brewery/:breweryId/locations
```

Comment: i figured it out kind of, i use withBreweies = y as url params and then i get the brewery with location belonging to that beer, but know i want to display a single beer with name of brewery but i get that it's undefined how can i acces breweries and display them in my component ?